# RadHtmlChart not displaying correctly

Tags: c#

I have this datatable

```
ID     Amount   Date
1       500         Feb 18
2       200         Feb 15 
3       400         Feb 18
4       800         Mar 18
5       300         Mar 19
```

i am making bar chart. In my chart months show in X-axis. I just to know how to represent this datatable to my chart.
And problem is that i have multiple amounts in same month i dont know how to show different amount bars in same month.
And Every bar on mouse hover  show amount. i dont want to show amount. i want to show Date on mouse hover in bar..

Please Help me how to do this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: May be you should start solving the problem at query level. Query the db to return the sum per each month.

Comment: i dont want to sum. i want how many amount for every month..

Comment: Can you add to your question the relevant code you're using? Is this really a C# question? Or is it a data source question? Or a Telerik question?